# Ask a question on conditional variance

Tags: probability, statistics

I see these lines in my textbook: mathematical statistics: basic ideas and selected topics: volume 1 (page 36).

$$E(Y-E(Y|Z))^2=Var Y -Var(E(Y|Z))=E(Y^2)-E[(E(Y|Z))^2]$$

I don't know how to get the above. The textbook said we need to use the law of total variance. But I still don't know how to get the above.

Comment: $Var(X)=E((X-E(X))^2)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$.  Apply this.

Comment: @herbsteinberg This is my first idea. But I didn't get from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$
Since $E[E(Y|Z)] = E(Y)$, writing $Y - E(Y|Z) = (Y - E(Y)) - (E(Y|Z) - E(Y))$ yields
\begin{align}
 & E[(Y - E(Y|Z))^2] \\
=& E[(Y - E(Y))^2] - 2E[(Y - E(Y))(E(Y|Z) - E(Y))] + E[(E(Y|Z) - E(Y))^2] \\
=& \Var(Y) - 2E[(Y - E(Y))(E(Y|Z) - E(Y))] + \Var(E(Y|Z)). \tag{1}
\end{align}
By the law of iterative expectation, the middle term in the right hand side of $(1)$ equals to (note that $E(Y|Z) - E(Y)$ is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable hence can be "taken out" in the first equality below):
\begin{align}
 & E\{E[(Y - E(Y))(E(Y|Z) - E(Y))|Z]\} \\
=& E\{[E(Y|Z) - E(Y)]E[Y - E(Y)|Z]\} \\
=& E\{[E(Y|Z) - E(Y)][E(Y|Z) - E(Y)]\} \\
=& E\{[E(Y|Z) - E(Y)]^2\} \\
=& \Var(E(Y|Z)).  \tag{2}
\end{align}
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ then proves the first equality.  The second equality is immediate by writing $\Var(Y)$ and $\Var(E(Y|Z))$ in terms of
\begin{align}
& \Var(Y) = E(Y^2) - [E(Y)]^2, \\
& \Var(E(Y|Z)) = E[(E(Y|Z))^2] - \{E[E(Y|Z)]\}^2
= E[(E(Y|Z))^2] - [E(Y)]^2.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand why $E(Y|Z)-E(Y)$ can be taken out when it is given Z. I can understand that when it is given Z, $E(Y|Z)$ now becomes a constant, since $E(Y|Z)$ is a random variable about $Z$. But what about $E(Y)$? If I think that any expectation is a number, then why $E(Y|Z)-E(Y)$ cannot be taken out when it is NOT given Z?

Comment: @Jackie $E(Y)$ is non-random (a constant real number!).  Now note that $E[c | \mathscr{G}] = c$ for any sub-$\sigma$-field $\mathscr{G}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{aligned}
\Bbb{E} \left[\left(Y-\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)\right)^{2}\right]
&=\Bbb{E} \left[\left(Y\color{red}{-\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)+\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)}-\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)\right)^{2}\right]\\
&=\Bbb{E} \left[\Bbb{E} \left\{\left(Y\color{red}{-\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)+\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)}-\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)\right)^{2}\Big|Z\right\}\right]\\
&=\Bbb{E} [\Bbb{Var} (Y|Z)]+\Bbb{E} \left[\left(\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)-\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)\right)^{2}\right]\\
&=\color{blue}{\Bbb{E} [\Bbb{Var} (Y|Z)]}\\
(\color{blue}{\text{Law of total variance}})&=\color{blue}{\operatorname {Var} (Y)-\operatorname {Var}(\Bbb{E} (Y|Z))}\\
(\color{green}{\text{Law of total expectation}})&=\left\{\Bbb E\left(Y^2\right)-[\color{green}{\Bbb E(Y)}]^2\right\}-\left\{\Bbb E\left([\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)]^2\right)-[\color{green}{\Bbb E(\Bbb{E} (Y|Z))}]^2\right\}\\
&=\Bbb E\left(Y^2\right)-\Bbb E\left([\Bbb{E} (Y|Z)]^2\right)
\end{aligned}